# 'same level factors' error in confusion matrix

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I keep on getting an error for confusion matrix. I get an error for table function too

```
advertising <- read.csv('C:/Users/matpo/Desktop/advertising_1.csv', stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
LogMod <- glm(Clicked.on.Ad ~ Daily.Time.Spent.on.Site + Age + Area.Income, data=advertising, family=binomial(link="logit"))
predicted <- predict(LogMod, advertising, type="response") 
#matrix below 
glm.pred <- ifelse(predicted > 0.8, "click", "not_click")
table(glm.pred, Clicked.on.Ad)
confusionMatrix(glm.pred, advertising)
```

The error I get:

```
Error in table(glm.pred, Clicked.on.Ad) : 
  object 'Clicked.on.Ad' not found
> confusionMatrix(glm.pred, advertising)
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

Could you please point me where I am making a mistake?

Comment: `Clicked.on.Ad` is a variable in the dataframe `advertising`; so try `advertising$Clicked.on.Ad`

Comment: @user20650 does not work. unfortunately. I get the same error :(

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only guess at what the issues are as I don't have your data to reproduce. But you use `confusionMatrix(glm.pred, advertising)` and from your code `advertising` is a `data.frame` not a column so it clearly shouldn't work. You also use `table(glm.pred, Clicked.on.Ad)` but from your `glm` call `Clicked.on.Ad` is a column within the `advertising` data.frame -- that is it does not exist outside of `advertising`, hence why you get that error.

Comment: @user20650 tha you for your comment! it actually worked for `table`, but didn't work for `confusionMatrix`

Comment: fixed it in confusion matrix too! Again, thank you!